# Question about what R-value means in linear regression

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

So I'm doing a study on how three variables affect happiness. I found that the three variables I'm studying are correlated somewhat to happiness.

However, I also found that the three variables have low R^2 values for each other; the variables are not strongly correlated with each other. Is this enough evidence to say that happiness is caused by single, isolated factors as opposed to a combination of factors?

Comment: $R^2$ in a regression printout is just the square of the Pearson correlation; the capital letter is probably a holdover from early computer terminals that used only upper case letters.// Intuitively, in regression of Y on x (predicting Y from x), $R^2$ is roughly the % of variability in Y that is 'explained' by regression on x, via the formula $S_{Y|x}^2 = \frac{n-1}{n-2}S_Y^2(1-r^2)$.

Comment: Correlation does not imply causation. But it may provide clues on what to investigate as causal factors.